# Send payload while sending message to an akka actor

Tags: scala, akka, actor, remote-actors

Is there a way to add some kind of `payload` (attached message) while sending a message to an akka actor? I know there is a way to do this using `routers`, but can this be achieved by simple message passing?

By simple message passing, I mean something like this `remoteActor ! "hi"`.

Comment: You can send any `Serializable` instance you like as a message. Custom-crafted case classes are commonly used for this, holding whatever payload you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, yes you can. You can send any payload you want but it has to be immutable (as far as i know). Most of people use case class-es. For example.

```
case class Payload(pay: List[String], load: Int)
```

then you can do as follows

```
actorRef ! Payload(List("string1","1gnirts"),69)
```

but you hve to remember to create appropriate case in receive

```
def receive = 
   case Payload(pay,load) => doSomeStuff(load,pay)
```